# Problem with my program with ruby, i don't understand

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, while-loop, break

```
puts "Quel âge tu as ?"

print ">"

age = gets.chomp.to_i
i = 0

    
while age > 0 

    

    puts "Il y a " + age.to_s + " ans" + " tu avais : " + i.to_s + " ans"
    age -= 1
    i += 1 

    break if age = i
    puts "Il y a " + age.to_s + " ans" + " tu avais la moitié de ton âge !"
    age = i
end
```

I have a problem with my program on Ruby On Rails. I apologize in advance for my English.

I train on this language by doing an exercise that allows you to enter your age, and to see how old you are in a given year.

But for example. When we reach half our age, for example 20 years old I want to display (in french)

"Ten years ago, you were half your age!"

that I wanted to put thanks to the "break if", but that produces only one line of code.
I hope you have understood otherwise do not hesitate to ask for clarification.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `break if age == i`, notice ==. Single `=` means assignment.

Comment: Do you want the loop to stop when reaching half the age? Or should it just produce a different output for that particular year and keep looping?

Comment: It must keep turning except when the age is equal to i

Comment: @MJoestar `break` stops the loop. You want `if age == i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` does not necessarily need to be a one-line you can have `break` all by itself after a condition is met, also you have an issue in your code where you are comparing with an `=` instead of a `==`

```rb
if (condition == true)
  break 
end
```

your code could look like

```rb
puts "Quel âge tu as ?"

print ">"

age = gets.chomp.to_i
i = 0

    
while age > 0 

    

    puts "Il y a " + age.to_s + " ans tu avais : " + i.to_s + " ans"
    age -= 1
    i += 1 

    if age == i
        puts "Il y a " + age.to_s + " ans tu avais la moitié de ton âge !"
        break
    end
end
```

*Note: may I also point that your code will not show `"Ten years ago, you were half your age!"` if the age entered is odd*

Comment: Nice ! My "while" work thanks but why does my while stop directly after the "if break", knowing that age is no longer equal to i the loop should resume?

Comment: the `break` will stop the while iteration, this is what your original code is meant to do

Comment: Thanks dude ! Amazing

Comment: If you do not want to stop the while loop just supress the 'break'.
You can also write it like this :
`next unless age == i # This stop the loop for this element only : jump to next element`

Answer (score 0):

A [`break` statement](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement) stops your while loop. You probably want an [`if` expression](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-if+Expression):

```
while age > 0
  if age == i
    puts "Il y a #{age} ans tu avais la moitié de ton âge !"
  else
    puts "Il y a #{age} ans tu avais : #{i} ans"
  end
  age -= 1
  i += 1
end
```

You can get rid of the manual incrementing / decrementing by using [`downto`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Integer.html#downto-method) and [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerator.html#with_index-method):

```
age.downto(1).with_index do |a, i|
  if a == i
    puts "Il y a #{a} ans tu avais la moitié de ton âge !"
  else
    puts "Il y a #{a} ans tu avais : #{i} ans"
  end
end
```